# Using variables for site when trying to download untrusted certificate file via WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to access a DoD file with a certificate that's untrusted. I'm able to use code found in this [Original Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55188751/assign-the-2nd-tab-of-ie-to-an-object-variable/55189497#55189497) but need to modify it to allow variables.

The web address/file is:
https://www.defensetravel.dod.mil/Docs/perdiem/browse/Allowances/Per_Diem_Rates/Text_Only/OCONUS-Overseas/2019/ovs19-03.xls

The part in the sub that first calls the GetFile sub I have:

```
downloadURL = "https://www.defensetravel.dod.mil/Docs/perdiem/browse/Allowances/Per_Diem_Rates/Text_Only/OCONUS-Overseas/2019/ovs" & strTwoDigitYear & "-" & strTwoDigitMonth & ".xls"
```

Both variables in the URL change dependent upon month and year (as the web address/file is named). Then my GetFile sub is:

```
Public Sub GetFile(ByVal downloadURL As String)
Debug.Print DownloadFile("C:\Users\craig\Raw DOD Files\", downloadURL)
End Sub
```

The Public function then runs but gets an error on line: http.Send. The error is "Run-time error '-2147012851 (80072f0d)': The certificate authority is invalid or incorrect." The variable still has scope and the link is correct so I'm curious to know whether there's something with the WinHttp that would prevent using variables as I'm not experience with using WinHttp.

```
Public Function DownloadFile(ByVal downloadFolder As String, ByVal downloadURL As String) As String
    Dim http As Object, tempArr As Variant
    Set http = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    http.Open "GET", downloadURL, False
    http.Option(4) = intSslErrorIgnoreFlags
    http.Send
    On Error GoTo errhand
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Open
        .Type = 1
        .write http.responseBody
        tempArr = Split(downloadURL, "/")
        tempArr = tempArr(UBound(tempArr))
        .SaveToFile downloadFolder & tempArr, 2  '< "/" on enter of downloadFolder. 2 for overwrite which is Ok if no file modifications.
        .Close
    End With
    DownloadFile = downloadFolder & tempArr
    Exit Function
errhand:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
        MsgBox "Download failed"
    End If
    DownloadFile = vbNullString
End Function
```

Comment: Are you remembering the const flag at the top?

Comment: Sorry, yes, the const flag is at the top of my module. I just didn't want to include all the unnecessary bits of that first part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (ensuring const flag is present)

```
Option Explicit
Const IGNORE_SSL_ERROR_FLAG As Long = 13056
Public Sub test()
    GetFile "https://www.defensetravel.dod.mil/Docs/perdiem/browse/Allowances/Per_Diem_Rates/Text_Only/OCONUS-Overseas/2019/ovs19-03.xls"
End Sub
Public Sub GetFile(ByVal downloadURL As String)
    Debug.Print DownloadFile("C:\Users\craig\Raw DOD Files\", downloadURL)
End Sub

Public Function DownloadFile(ByVal downloadFolder As String, ByVal downloadURL As String) As String
    Dim http As Object, tempArr As Variant
    Set http = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    http.Open "GET", downloadURL, False
    http.Option(4) = IGNORE_SSL_ERROR_FLAG
    http.send
    On Error GoTo errhand
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Open
        .Type = 1
        .write http.responseBody
        tempArr = Split(downloadURL, "/")
        tempArr = tempArr(UBound(tempArr))
        .SaveToFile downloadFolder & tempArr, 2  '< "/" on enter of downloadFolder. 2 for overwrite which is Ok if no file modifications.
        .Close
    End With
    DownloadFile = downloadFolder & tempArr
    Exit Function
errhand:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
        MsgBox "Download failed"
    End If
    DownloadFile = vbNullString
End Function
```

Comment: I swear my code looked so close to yours that I can't figure out why what I had wasn't working but your code, at least, is working. I sincerely appreciate it. One last thing, could you tell me the purpose of debug.print DownloadFile? I never knew you could use debug.print in this manner or why we would. Why debug.print over Call or Run DownloadFile?

Comment: It is only because I wanted to return the final download name of the file. You can re-write to run as a sub and not return anything.  Debug.Print writes to the immediate window Ctrl + G